# How to detect USB storage in Qt?

Tags: qt, libusb

**Target**: In our embedded Linux system, we want to use Qt to detect the insertion of a USB storage device, to inform the system when the USB storage device is plugged in or out, then we can mount its file system. Later we can access the files on the USB storage device.

I searched a little, it seems there are two solutions: libusb and dbus. But I still don't know how to use it. Does anyone have some examples?

Comment: The USB pen should be a pointer device, isn't it? Are you sure if it is installed properly? And because you are using Linux, it is very possible to access the specific USB events using Xorg. I hope someone will come up with a nice solution.

Comment: @Md.MinhazulHaque The question doesn't refer to an input device, but to a storage device, known in some places as a usb pen drive.

Comment: "I searched a little, it seems there are two solutions: [...] dbus." DBus is not a solution to this concrete problem, it's a messaging bus. You are probably talking about some service that communicates via DBus (probably udisks).

Comment: @Kuba Ober Yes, only the storage device. Because our users will put some files in it, and the QT program on the PCB board should access these files.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to [auto-mount](https://www.axllent.org/docs/view/auto-mounting-usb-storage/) USB storage is via [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev). Udev can [notify you](https://bitbucket.org/dfrank/my-udev-notify/src) when a device is added/mounted. You could talk to [udisks](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/udisks/) via dbus to be notified of storage addition/removal as well.

libusb is only tangentially related, you shouldn't be using it unless you wish to reimplement a lot of already existing code.

Comment: Do you have any example code for this? As I understand, it is through kernel->hotplug->udev->hal/udisks->dbus.

Comment: @James.Zhou The links I've posted contain some examples that bypass dbus - that should be sufficient. I don't have any links handy for dbus examples, but google should be your friend.